# Why can't all people answer their own questions?

Tags: discussion, privileges, self-answer, help-suggestion

People should be able to submit an answer to their one question no matter their reputation.

I just got an answer to a question of mine from someone I knew, but I can't submit my answer any way other than a comment which has a limit to the amount of words which is too small for my explanation. 
How should I answer my question and why can't people answer their questions; why do they need a specific reputation?

Comment: Just to clarify, the OP is probably talking here about limit of 15 reputation points you need to answer your own question - [see help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). There is also additional limitation that users with less that 100 reputation points have to [wait 8 hours before they can answer their own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186).

Comment: Why? What if I have a great answer and I can't submit it?

Comment: GoalBike I have posted my comment in an effort to clarify what your post here is actually about. (I am not sure whether this is what you meant or not.) This question could certainly be improved a bit. For example, you have tagged this (feature-request) but it is not clear what exactly is the feature you want to implement. And wording of your question seems to suggest that you are mainly asking why the things are currently implemented the way they are - in which case (feature-request) tag probably does not fit the question.

Comment: I guess the idea is that random people should not be allowed to post any question they like with a (wrong?) answer, and so a minimal threshold of 15 rep is there to hopefully prevent nonsense answers from cluttering the site. I don't know how effective it actually is, and don't really care, since 15 rep is very easy to get; just 3 upvotes on your questions or 1.5 upvotes on your answers.

Comment: And it seems that I was incorrect about the 8 hour limit - the post I linked to is obsolete, this rule was later abolished. See [Clarify the “8 hour delay” self-answer message to discourage self-answering with edits or comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237136#237916) and also 2014-08-12 entry in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445).

Comment: Hint: anyone can actually self-answer their own question *after* they post it.

Comment: @GoalBike [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414797/finding-the-percentage-to-scale-in-img) in on hold, i.e. closed. Nobody can post answers on closed question, even as the author. This got nothing to do with self answer.

Comment: I've voted to reopen to give the OP an opportunity to post his own answer. If, after all that, the OP's posts are still found wanting, then we can close again.

Comment: I voted for reopening, but mainly to give the OP a chance to revise it: it's **not** really a coincidence that the upvoted and accepted answer starts with "I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for".

Comment: @ProfessorVector:  The OP has "a chance to revise it" even before the Question is reopened.   In fact, by editing the Question it will likely be automatically placed in the Reopen Review Queue.